# Running PAServer on Mac through PAClient.exe manually

Tags: ios, macos, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to copy the application file for iOS or MacOS to my MacOS PAServer directly instead of using IDE.

If I use .bat file to run PASERVER commands that I copied from Delphi's compile logs (at the bottom of screen), why does the PASERVER commands not work properly?

NOTE: this script is run after the project is MAKE or BUILD already.

```
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --Clean="project1.app,c:\PROJECT1\project1._@emb_.tmp" -u8 --Clean="project1.app.dSYM,c:\PROJECT1\project1._@emb_.tmp" -u8 --Clean="project1.launchscreen,c:\PROJECT1\project1._@emb_.tmp" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_APPL_180.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_APPL_180.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="d:\temp\Release\project1.entitlements,project1.app\..\,1,project1.entitlements" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_LAUNCH_344x594_a.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\LaunchScreenImage.imageset\,1,FM_LaunchScreenImage_iPadDark@2x.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="d:\temp\Release\project1,project1.app\,1,project1" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="d:\temp\Release\project1.launchscreen\**\*.*,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\,0" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_SETTINGS_87x87.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_SETTINGS_87x87.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="d:\temp\Release\project1.info.plist,project1.app\,1,Info.plist" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_LAUNCH_458x.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\LaunchScreenImage.imageset\,1,FM_LaunchScreenImage_iPhoneDark@2x.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_APPL_120.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_APPL_120.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_IPAD_APPL_167x167.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_IPAD_APPL_167x167.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_APPL_1024x1024.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_APPL_1024x1024.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_SPOTLIGHT_800.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_SPOTLIGHT_80x80.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_NOTIFY2_60.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_NOTIFY2_60x60.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_LAUNCH_1688.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\LaunchScreenImage.imageset\,1,FM_LaunchScreenImage_iPhoneDark@3x.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_LAUNCH_229.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\LaunchScreenImage.imageset\,1,FM_LaunchScreenImage_iPad@2x.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_SETTINGS_58.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_SETTINGS_58x58.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_IPAD_APPL_152.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_IPAD_APPL_152.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --put="IC_NOTIFY2_40.png,project1.app\..\project1.launchscreen\Assets\AppIcon.appiconset\,1,IC_NOTIFY2_40.png" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --assetcatalog="project1.launchscreen/Assets,project1.app" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --storyboard="project1.launchscreen/LaunchScreen.storyboard,project1.app" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --Put="/Users/delphi/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/14537af0-24a8-47eb-8a8e-4f5fec1f5e7a.mobileprovision,project1.app,embedded.mobileprovision" "Macbook"
"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe" -u8 --codesign="project1.app,'Apple Development: someaddress@gmail.com (H3ZK9VK5AA)',project1.app\..\project1.entitlements" "Macbook"
```

but when I run it

almost every file is:

Connecting to 192.168.1.100 on port 64211...
Copying file(s)...
Total file(s) copied: 0 file(s)  0 bytes

or

Connecting to 192.168.1.53 on port 64211...
Error: E6665 Stream read error

Please advise how to call PACLIENT directly so that I can deploy my IOS or MacOS app directly. I have checked this forum for examples.

Delphi 10.4.1 compiling to MacOS Big Sur

Comment: An application bundle is created on the OSX machine from the various files sent over. It is that bundle you can run/deploy on other systems.

Comment: Connecting to 192.168.1.100 on port 64211...
Error: E0264 Unable to execute '"/usr/bin/codesign" --deep -s "Apple Development: someaddress@gmail.com (H3ZK9VK5AA)" -f "/Users/delphi/PAServer/scratch-dir/MacBook/ios4.app"' (Error 1)
Error: E0264 /Users/delphi/PAServer/scratch-dir/Macbook/ios4.app: main executable failed strict validation